# Knockout custom binding to a computed column

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a custom binding for "money". It will insert a dollar sign at the beginning, and also adds columns for every 3 digits left of the decimal. Also, that same column is a ko.computed column.

What I'm having trouble with, I have to format that column as a setter:

```
myColumn.myValue(functionToGenerateNewValue(parameter)()); //notice the parens after the function to actually retrieve the value
```

in order to have it be able to do the money binding correctly. But if I want the computed value to work on the fly, then it has to be setup this way:

```
myColumn.myValue = ko.computed(functionToGenerateNewValue(parameter));
```

Here's the code for the money binding:

```
var cleanInput = function (value) {
    return parseFloat(value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, ''));
}

ko.bindingHandlers.money = {
    init: function (elm, valueAccessor) {
        $(elm).change(function () {
            valueAccessor()(cleanInput(elm.value));
        }).addClass('money');
    },
    update: function (elm, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())
        $elm = $(elm),
        method = $elm.is(":input") ? "val" : "html";
        $elm[method](formatCurrency(value));
    }
};
```

When this gets called as a computed value, the elm.value is the part that fails, since that contains a function instead of a value.

Any idea how to mix these two implementations together?

Edit: Here's my new version that I'm still kind of stuck on...

```
if (goalMonth > viewModel.LastProcessedMonth()) {
                    if (goal.LYMonthSales() === goal.LYMonthSalesActual()) {

                        goal.LYMonthSales = ko.computed({
                            read: generateTotalSales(goalMonth),
                            write: function (newValue) {
                                goal.LYMonthSales(newValue);
                            }
                        });
                        goal.LYMonthSalesComputed = ko.computed({
                            read: goal.LYMonthSales,
                            write: function (newValue) {
                                goal.LYMonthSales(newValue);
                            }
                        });
                        //goal.LYMonthSales(generateTotalSales(goalMonth)());
                    }

                    goal.LYMonthSalesActual = ko.computed(generateTotalSales(goalMonth));
                    //goal.LYMonthSalesActual(generateTotalSales(goalMonth)());
                }
```

The "LYMonthSales" used to be shown on the view, but now I'm showing the "LYMonthSalesComputed".

Now, the "write" is not writing the value to the LYMonthSales property. (When calling my save, the original value still exists)

Comment: Check out Sanderson's new Projections library :: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/12/03/knockout-projections-a-plugin-for-efficient-observable-array-transformations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a [writeblae computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).  That will allow you to specify logic for writing a new value to your computed.  Something like this:

```
myColumn.myValue = ko.computed({
    read: functionToGenerateNewValue(parameter),
    write: function(newVal){
       //now manually provide the logic to handle a new value
    },
    owner: myColumn //optional - will cause the `this` value to be correct
});
```

Comment: can you look at my updated question, I'm still having some issues implementing the writable computed observable...